# "cannot open input file odbc32.lib" error in 64-bit Win 7 when compiling a Qt application in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, qt, 64-bit

I have Win7 64 bit machine and installed Qt library for VS2008 on the machine.

After creating blank Qt application, I get an error  "cannot open input file odbc32.lib" when compiling the app in VS 2008. I believe that's a wrong message in several aspects. My machine is 64 bit and surely does not have the library. And why it requires that library for blank app. Is there any way to remove it from linker options? Can anybody give a clue how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you building using VS or using QT creator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved the problem by including Windows SDK library directory (e.g., `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Lib\x64`) and its executable directory in VS 2008. And I was wrong. odbc32.ib is still a 64-bit library